# How to position CardViews next to each other?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to make `Google PlayStore-like-CardView layout`. However, I do not manage to put Card Views side-by-side, rather they are being listed Vertically, top down.

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image: Screenshot]

**cardview.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_appicon"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_appname"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_appname" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="App Name"
                android:id="@+id/tv_appname"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_appicon"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Any ideas how can I put those CardViews side-by-side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting them inside a linear layout with width match_parent, height wrap_content, orientation horizontal ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_appicon"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_appname"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_appname" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_appname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_appicon"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:text="App Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_appicon2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_appname2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_appname2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_appname2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_appicon2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:text="App Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have not, will try now and let you know.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but still the same happens as in my screenshot posted above.

Comment: ive posted code above, it works for me 100%. just changed the id's due to conflict so set them according to your code

Comment: Ah, OK, yea, now it would work, but this means I need to hardcode CardViews. I do not know how many of them will there be when user uses it. I will dynamically assign Card contents. Or did I miss something ? Is it possible with this too - without too much code?

Comment: can you share the code you use to dynamically attach cardviews?

Comment: in this link: http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/
I use identical Adapter for RecyclerView, I followed this tutorial.

Comment: edit your question, it doesnt mention anything about a recyclerview. use GridLayoutManager or StaggeredGridLayoutManager instead of LinearLayoutManger when you set recyclerView.setLayoutManager