# Xamarin.forms How can I show items next each other in a list

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I am currently developing an app using **Xamarin.Forms** with .Net standard sharing strategy. Everything is done in the shared project. (No device specifies designs).

I try to bind a list of objects to a listview. I already show/fill the list with `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` The selected item is bound to the listview as well `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedApp}"`.
Each listItem is visualized as a frame with an image and a title.
By using a datatemplate.

What I try to achieve is make my listview look like a "Google PlayStore-like-List":
[image: List with items next each other]

showing the items next each other.
When there is horizontally no place left, the items next items will show on a next line. The list automatically adapts the items to the available with.
This way, the list is better screen responsive when switching from portrait to landscape.

**My question is how, can I show the list in this structure?**
However it would be nice, the Material design card design is not a part of this problem.

This question describe a similar my problem what I try to become.
Expect I am developing a Xamarin app and not a Native (java) Android app:
[How to position CardViews next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140558/how-to-position-cardviews-next-to-each-other)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a control named `FlowListView` (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView/))

Just add the NuGet package and add the view from your XAML

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Type}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Small" />
                <local:Rating Value="{Binding Rating}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</flv:FlowListView>
```

(don't forget to add `flv` namespace).

Of course this assumes that the items in your `FlowListView` have the properties `Image`, `Type`, `Name` and `Rating`. Furthermore I've assumed the existence of a control named `Rating` to display the rating of the service. Of course you'll have to adapt the actual code to your property names and to your needs, but basically this should do.

I have not tried the control myself, hence I don't know about scolling. You might have to wrap the `FlowListView` in a `ScrollView`, but it might as well work out of the box.

**EDIT**

To adapt the number of columns you can override `OnSizeAllocated` on your page, then determine the orientation and set the `FlowColumnCount` accordingly (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated/p/System.Double/System.Double/) and [here](https://www.wintellect.com/responding-to-orientation-changes-in-xamarin-forms/)).

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); // Important!

    if (width != _width || height != _height)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;

        if(width > height)
        {
            FlowListView.FlowColumnCount = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            FlowListView.FlowColumnCount = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that we've added `x:Name="FlowListView` to out `FlowListView`. Even better would be to calculate the number of columns based on the actual width, but I think you've got the gist.

Comment: I can confirm that scrolling will work without adding `ScrollView`.

Comment: Paul Kertscher advice is very helpful and is nearly what I want,
However there are still some problems with this solution. 

1. I work with MVVM. the selectedItem from the listview was binded with a Object/Property of the VM of that page. When I select an item from the FlowListView, databinding wont work any more.

2. With your answer, FlowColumnCount is fixed at 3. What I trying to do is, as soon there is enough space by expanding the window, show an extra item (increase FlowColumnCount ) . If there is not enough space by shrinking the window, FlowColumnCount must be reduced.

Comment: @John: Regarding point 1: I don't really see, why data binding should not work. You have the `FlowLastTappedItem` property which you can bind to your VM. (See [here](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView))

Comment: @PaulKertscher:
Thanks, I almost be there.

Point 2 is solved, I used SelectedItem which was wrong.
When I do your solution in code behind, everything works!
However, I need to respect MVVM frameworks, which means I shouldn't type code in the code behind but in the ViewModel (VM) of that page.
In the ViewModel, I can't reach list flowListView (name of element) and can't get the page/views, width;

When I can reach the same result respecting the MVVM pattern,
no code behind, my problem is really solved.


I already really happy with your previous advice.

Comment: @John: The VM in MVVM should *not* be responsible for *how* something is displayed (at least not on that low level), but rather for *what* is displayed. Having code that is purely presentation relevant should not be a concern of your VM, but rather of your view.