# Xamarin.Forms How can I make a view adpative while using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

Referring to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066017/xamarin-forms-how-can-i-show-items-next-each-other-in-a-list), I needed some help making a view/page responsive while keep respecting the **MVVM patern**.
In my previous question, I learned how to adept the view by overriding the OnSizeAllocated methode in the 'code behind'. And it works well.

However when using, the MVVM pattern (MvvmLightLibsStd10), it is not allowed/recommanded to write code in the 'code behind' of a view.

**How can I change/adapt the view in the ViewModel, instead of the code behind of a view?**

I am still using Xamarin.Forms with .Net standard code sharing strategy.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  Could you use OnIdom in the xaml to achieve this.  
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="StackOrientation">
        <OnIdiom.Phone>Vertical</OnIdiom.Phone>
        <OnIdiom.Tablet>Horizontal</OnIdiom.Tablet>
    </OnIdiom>
    </StackLayout.Orientation>

Comment: I'm not sure if my understanding of MVVM pattern is correct, but please allow me to share it with you. The 'rules' are: 1 - don't let the View decide what or when present the data; 2 - The ViewModel decides all the behavior of data shown; 3 - XAML / cs are two sides of the same coin - and some things you can't do in XAML; 4 - the point about the mvvm don't recommend to write code on view is that it's often non-reusable despite it's very useful feature.

Comment: I completely agree with [@PaulKertscher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49066996/8093394). If you need something more [you can write your own 'flowview' layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom/), remember that when coding Views even [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) uses the MVC pattern, I bet it's a better approach to do what is needed, once it's focused on a visual component and it's visual behaviors instead of data presentation/manipulation...

Comment: I don't think MVVM discourage the devs to write in the code-behind file especially if behaviour you're trying to do is related to the Control itself i.e animations, size changed, appearance, ...
ViewModel mostly handles business logic